# Error: Unexpected end of stream. Data might be corrupted

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream, lz4

I'm trying something with stream data. I'm getting an error. I have some codes like below. One of both works, but another is not.

This code works properly.

```
    private static void Main_2()
    {
        {
            var i = 1000000;

            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, i);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Stream mem = File.Create("test.lz4");
            LZ4EncoderStream target = LZ4Stream.Encode(mem);
            ms.CopyTo(target);
            target.Dispose();
            ms.Dispose();
            mem.Dispose();
        }

        {
            Stream source = File.OpenRead("test.lz4");
            LZ4DecoderStream target = LZ4Stream.Decode(source);
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            target.CopyTo(mem);

            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            mem.Position = 0;
            var i = (int)bf.Deserialize(mem);

            mem.Dispose();
            target.Dispose();
            source.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't work.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var m = new MemoryStream();

        {
            var i = 1000000;

            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, i);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Stream mem = new MemoryStream();
            LZ4EncoderStream target = LZ4Stream.Encode(mem);
            ms.CopyTo(target);
            m = new MemoryStream(((MemoryStream)mem).ToArray());
            target.Dispose();
            ms.Dispose();
            mem.Dispose();
        }

        {
            Stream source = m;
            LZ4DecoderStream target = LZ4Stream.Decode(source);
            var mem = new MemoryStream();
            target.CopyTo(mem);

            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            mem.Position = 0;
            var i = (int)bf.Deserialize(mem);

            mem.Dispose();
            target.Dispose();
            source.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

What is difference between these codes ? I couldn't find anything. Why is working with FileStream, Why is not working with MemoryStream? Can you explain this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure everything is flushed. Move the extraction point down:

```
//m = new MemoryStream(((MemoryStream)mem).ToArray());
target.Dispose();
ms.Dispose();
mem.Dispose();
m = new MemoryStream(((MemoryStream)mem).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But really I thought that I cannot get stream data unless dispose it. Why should I flush it before create a new memorystream data ?

Comment: "Unexpected end of stream" usually means a stream wasn't properly closed/flushed. Here I think it was `target`. In this case it is safe to close them all.