# Is there memory Leak in Serializer

Tags: c#, .net

In the below code, is there any part in the code which can cause memory leak?
Can XmlSerializer cause memory leak?

```
public static string Serializer<T>(T tag, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        if (encoding == null)
            encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, encoding))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(tag.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, tag);

                using (StreamReader streamREader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, encoding))
                {
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    xmlBuilder.Append(streamREader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
            return xmlBuilder.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("{0} {1}", "Serializer failed ", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas.

Comment: @bommelding: `MemoryStream` is unusual in that regard, yes, and nothing really prevents you from doing so, but I also see no point at all. First, it's best practice to dispose locally constructed disposable instances using the `using` statement. Most static code analyzers will complain about not disposing the object, and you have one more thing to explain during code reviews. Second, accessing members of a disposed object should be almost always avoided. So I would prefer `using (var ms = MemoryStream()) { x = ms.ToArray(); }` any day of the week, if I really need to return the buffer.

Comment: @groo - that is drifting away from the point here, which was the false assumption like in the answer below. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988480/9695604) why the ToArray() should come _after_ the `using`.

Comment: @JerinSebastian - some useful comments were deleted here, did you see the one  about the generated assemblies?  You should respond to that. Currently your question is unclear.

Comment: @bommelding: your linked answer doesn't make sense: disposing a `MemoryStream` does [absolutely nothing to the data](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,147). Perhaps the OP's `LZ4Stream` does some flushing on dispose, but claiming that `ToArray()` must come after disposing `MemoryStream` is incorrect.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This is not my snippet, but I'd still like to hear a reason for disposing the `MemoryStream` before getting the array. The `Dispose` method simply does nothing related to the array. Giving advice to a novice programmer (presumably) that you should access an instance after disposing is, IMHO, a poor practice.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: [disposing a `MemoryStream` does absolutely nothing to the data](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,147). The only thing that happens is that future calls to most methods will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: @Groo - it certainly isn't incorrect but maybe a matter of taste. The linked answer did help someone out and I've seen that pattern a lot. You could take the array inside the `using (memstream)` but it has to be outside the `using(streamDecorator)`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're not disposing the "memoryStream" you declare on 6.

And something else: you won't see the memory gap regained until the GC passes... you can check that using [GC.Collect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257372/how-to-force-garbage-collector-to-run)

Comment: And it is important to note that manually forcing the GC to do its job can be problematic/cause minor performance issues. In 99.99999% of cases, waiting for it to determine it needs to run by itself is fine.

Comment: yes! correct! you should only do that to verify that there's no leak, and even there, thats not a 100% safe approach!

Comment: If you need to manually GC, you most likely have other issues. (Like not disposing of `memoryStream`.)

Comment: MemeoryStream.Dispose() disposes nothing. It's a dud, imposed by the base class Stream. It is not related to any memory issues the OP has.